# В каких ситуациях лучше использовать #define? c++

Tags: c++, define

Есть файл определения функций из класса, в котором перед каждой функцией прописано:

```
template <typename KEY_TYPE, typename VALUE_TYPE>
```

стоит ли 'задефайнить' эту строку и заменить ее на что-то более простое, наподобие:

```
#define TEMPLATE template <typename KEY_TYPE, typename VALUE_TYPE>
```

или же в этой ситуации это наоборот переусложнение кода?

Аналогичный вопрос с

```
CustomClass<KEY_TYPE, VALUE_TYPE>
```

используется еще чаще чем предыдущее.

Comment: Для с++ есть https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias

Comment: @こきん , я знаю я говорю вообще о практике "переименновывать" подобного типа обьекты

Comment: *"`CustomClass<KEY_TYPE, VALUE_TYPE>` используется еще чаще чем предыдущее"* По идее, в части мест его можно заменить на просто `CustomClass`. Со списком параметров он должен требоваться примерно столько же раз, сколько первый макрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос субъективный, но все равно отвечу. Ниже только мое мнение.

---

Мне кажется это все сомнительные варианты использования `#define`.

Сделайте названия параметров покороче, и будет не так неприятно их постоянно писать. Как вариант, перенесите функции в тело класса, все равно современные IDE умеют их сворачивать.

Макросы должны быть крайним средством. Они подходят:

- Для условной компиляции.
- Чтобы добиться соблюдения
  [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), если больше ничего не помогает. (А-ля "объявить enum и функции для его преобразования в строку и обратно".) Это не про ваш случай.
- Чтобы избежать особо некрасивого синтаксиса. ([Пример.](https://github.com/yuri-kilochek/boost.scope_guard))

И макросы должны быть максимально общими, не привязанными к предметной области или конкретному файлу (если это не какой-нибудь одноразовый [x-macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)).